# find min value and color it with vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find min value that color value is not fill with red color with Vba code
my code is here:

```
  Private Sub bidcanceled_Click()

  Dim HLF As Range, finalHLF
  Dim minNum As Double
  Dim Lastrow As Integer
  Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Set HLF = Range("e2:e" & Lastrow)
  Range("e2:e" & Lastrow).Select

  minNum = WorksheetFunction.MIN(HLF)
  finalHLF = HLF.Find(what:=minNum, Lookat:=xlWhole).Address
  Range(finalHLF).Interior.Color = vbGreen
  Range(finalHLF).Offset(, 3).Value = "bid canceled"

  End Sub
```

[image]

the output must choose the cell = 41 and fill the color with green can any one help to solve that, when i run the code it's choose 37 and fill it with green ..i want it to select non color values and find the min number in that column

Comment: I would suggest `AutoFilter` by color.

Comment: no it cant helped me for the next steps ..thanks any way @JvdV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I would suggest to implement an `AutoFilter` on color:

---

**<sub>Sample Data:</sub>**

[image]

---

**<sub>Sample Code:</sub>**

```
Sub Test()

Dim Lr As Long, MinVal As Long
Dim Rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Retrieve last used row on column E
    Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    'Apply our filter of non-colored cells
    Set Rng = .Range("E1:E" & Lr)
    Rng.AutoFilter 1, , 12

    'First check if any rows are filtered to prevent error on .SpecialCells and color the minimum
    If Rng.SpecialCells(12).Count > 1 Then
        MinVal = WorksheetFunction.min(Rng.SpecialCells(12))
        Rng.SpecialCells(12).Find(MinVal, Lookat:=xlWhole).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Rng.SpecialCells(12).Find(MinVal, Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(, 3).Value = "bid canceled"
    End If

    'Get rid of Filter
    Rng.AutoFilter

End With

End Sub
```

---

**<sub>Sample Result:</sub>**

[image]

Comment: if I changed  12 to 17 it will not work and gave me an error out of range on this line Rng.AutoFilter 1, , 12  @JvdV

Comment: @fatoomthk, why change to 17. The 12 is there with a purpose.

Comment: every time I have different range it's not fixed :| but I didnt understand the error

Comment: Then change range and field parameter and keep the rest of the filter untouched. The 12 has nothing to do with your range object